# How to use toLowerCase() to compare strings

Tags: jquery

How to use `toLowerCase()` to check if condition instead of writing like this `if (name == "admin" || name == "Admin")`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#click").click(function(){
var name=$('#input').val();

   if (name == "admin" || name == "Admin") {
       alert("success")
    }
    else{
    alert(failure)
    }
})
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="input">
<button id="click">
click me
</button>
```

I tried this for other example.Is it correct?

```
if ($("#levType option:selected").text().toLowerCase() == "Loss of pay") {
            alert("success")
        } else {
            alert("failure")
        }
```

Comment: You just call it on the string the make then comparison...? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase

Answer (score 1):

First convert it to lowercase and check against a lower case `"admin"`.

```
 if (name.toLowerCase() == "admin") {
       alert("success");
   }
```

**Update :**

```
if ($("#levType option:selected").text().toLowerCase() == "Loss of pay")
```

is not correct. SInce you converting it to lower case it `Loss of pay` should be

```
loss of pay
```

so your condition is

```
if ($("#levType option:selected").text().toLowerCase() == "loss of pay")
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `.toLowerCase()` after the string that you want to check.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#click").click(function(){
var name=$('#input').val();

   if (name.toLowerCase() == "admin") {
       alert("success")
    }
    else{
    alert(failure)
    }
})
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="input">
<button id="click">
click me
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here it it,

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#click").click(function(){
var name=$('#input').val();

   if (name.toLowerCase() == 'admin') {
       alert("success")
    }
    else{
    alert('failure');
    }
})
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="input">
<button id="click">
click me
</button>
```

This is the basically what you need. in your snippet you have made some syntext error too, take care of this too. Hope this will help you!